# Clarification about Hashirama's Senjutsu?

Tags: naruto

I was browsing about Hashirama's sage mode. What I could procure was that he went to Shikkotsu woods to learn the wood style and the sage mode respective to that.

> Shikkotsu Forest (湿骨林, Shikkotsurin, English TV: Shikkotsu Woods, Literally meaning: Damp Bone Forest) is one of the big three unexplored sage regions, a legendary place that is equally famous as the other two: Mount Myōboku and Ryūchi Cave. It is the home of the slug Katsuyu, parts of which are summoned by Tsunade and her disciple Sakura Haruno. - [source](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shikkotsu_Forest)

How did Hashirama come to know about this forest which is the home of slugs? And what was his background to learning the Senjutsu?
Additional question that arises is that Does this mean both Tsunade and Sakura can learn the sage Jutsu?

Comment: I included the source from where you quoted in your message. If you quote something from an external source, you should include it as well.

Comment: much appreciated @Dimitrimx

Comment: Probably lucky stumble. He walks around and luckily stumbles upon it.

Comment: ya the Hokage wanders around instead of running the village or before that fighting for his clan. lol

Comment: There's nothing anywhere that says Hashi learned sage mode from Shikkotsurin forest

Comment: Additionally, while it says Hagoromo learned sage mode from the toads, that he was able to sense natural energy before he was trained. Theoretically Hashirama could have had the same innate attunement to Senjutsu, perhaps even more so because of his natural Wood Release style being very nature-oriented.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question,

> How did Hashirama come to know about this forest which is the home of slugs

There is no mention of how Hashirama found this place or that he learned senjutsu there. But if he did, it could be speculated that he either stumbled upon it, or he researched scrolls or other historical artifacts that led him there. Much like how Kabuto managed to find Ryūchi cave.

> what was his background to learning the Senjutsu

nothing on this was mentioned either on the manga or the anime.

> Does this mean both Tsunade and Sakura can learn the sage Jutsu?

By transitive property of equality, we can say that Tsunade and Sakura could master the sage mode, however it has been stated by Kakashi that Sakura has the least amount of chakra among the members of team 7. Also, it has been stated that a large chakra pool is required in order to amass nature energy. So that could be a handicap for Sakura. However, as her training progressed if she managed to increase her chakra pool, then theoretically she should be able to master senjutsu. The same goes for Tsunade.

Madara was shown to be able to control sage chakra, without having any training in it.